# prevent enter on submit button only, not the rest of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, preventdefault, enter

ok, so i've been searching for a piece of code that does this, and nothing applies to my situation.

My Problem: i'm trying to prevent the form from submitting when the "ENTER" key is pressed but allowing the my search script thats inside the form to submit when the enter key is pressed.

What i've found are scripts that prevent the Enter key period, or the script doesn't work because i think i'm using a `<button>` instead of a `<input>` as my submit button, i'm not really sure.

my form

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" id="myform">
```

my javascript that does my search

```
    function showSub(str) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str=="") {
      document.getElementById("txtSub").innerHTML="";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("txtSub").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","findLogo.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}  
$(document).on('change', '#searchText', function() {
// Get the search text
var searchText = $(this).val();
// Make sure it isn't empty
    if (searchText.length > 0) {
        // Send the update request
        showSub(searchText);
    }
});
```

my search input

```
<input type="text" id="searchText" value="" />
<div id="txtSub"></div>
```

my submit button

```
<input type="hidden" value="Post" name="submit" /> 
<button type="submit" style="height:33px; width:50px">
<img src="../css/images/plus_25.png" />
</button>
```

my java-script post submit script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('button[type=submit]').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "postadd.php",
            data: $("#myform").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<div class="success"><img src="../images/loading-blue.gif" width="25" /></div>');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
                //document.getElementById('footer').scrollIntoView();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by not rest of the form

Comment: i have a search script that is in the form itself that i want to execute a search when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: I don't get it, that form will never be submitted as you return false in the inline onsubmit for the form, so what are you really trying to do here ?

Comment: the return false is for my ajax script that submits the form on another page. once the `<button>` is pressed it send its to postadd.php. so the page doesn't go to another page, it stays on the same page. The Way my form works now, is any text field, when you press enter, triggers the submit button and causes the form to give an error. I want to prevent the form from submitting when the enter key when it's physically pressed but NOT prevent the enter key from being used in my search field input.

Comment: Most scripts now simply prevent all the form text fields from using enter and that solved their problem, but i have a search input on my form that I would like to have the user hit enter in order to complete their search. So Enter key is allowed in the text field, but not allowed to submit the form itself.

Comment: @Sickest found a solution it gets the work done check it out give your feed backs

Comment: @You left the chat room??

Answer (score 1):

**The Solution is basically based on detecting keypress and preventing form submission**

1. First of all make two buttons for searching and form submission as `<input type="button" />`
2. To differentiate between search button and submit button add classes to it with your suitable name  here  I added `.submit` and `.Search`
3. Another thing , chaining is used on `.submit button` it is used to prevent click event block from executing if key pressed is enter key
4. With preventing submission with enter key results in another problem if any other button is click by selecting that button form will enter to prevent that else case is also added which prevents button based form submission with submit button and another plus point is you can add any custom button for submission
5. Next the Click block submits the form which is reached by passing through step 4 which  stops if key press was cause of starting to execute the process

---

***Two Examples added one with submit button based on click only another for search based on both click/Enter***

**Another Plus point is that it does not prevent you from using enter for search button**

### [Solved Click for demo To know the difference submit with enter key and search with enter key](http://jsfiddle.net/Me58a/3/)

### HTML

```
<input type="button" class="Submit" value="Submit"/>

<input type="button" class="Search"  value="Search"/>
```

### Jquery

```
$("input.Submit").keypress(function(event){

    if(event.which=='13'){

        alert("Key enter key entered ");
     event.preventDefault();



 }else{
      event.preventDefault();
    }


}).click(function(event){
    alert("Here is the submit Button works on click write jquery ");

  $( "#FormId" ).submit();
});


//The Code For Search Which could be triggered by both keypress and click


  $("input.Search").click(function(event){

              alert("Works for both enter and click");
            });
```

**EDIT:**

### [Demo With Search just like google on entering text to search on text box and clicking enter triggers the search](http://jsfiddle.net/Me58a/6/)

***The enter some text in search box press enter key***

### Jquery

```
$("input.Search").keypress(function(event){

          if(event.which=='13'){

            alert("Key enter key entered ");

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do I have to have a search button for the search field? I want the user to be able to press enter to search.

Comment: For simple explanation purpose only i had added it to explain the difference the first block will only be triggered if corresponding button was clicked i mean button with .submit class attached so you are free to use enter key any where else for what ever purposes currently

Comment: also, i don't know if its just jfiddle, but when i press "enter" nothing happen. aside from that

Comment: hit tab first it will select the submit button and press enter and press another tab to get into text box type some text and press enter.To know difference click submit button then you will see

Comment: @Sickest have you checked the fiddle

Comment: i didnt get you if what you asked was how to modify this code then just add id to form so that form submission can be made and instead of alert write your code to search on the block for search this will get your work done